# Filter 50k+ rows by allowed or blocked value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb, dynamic-columns

I have database with about 50k (and counting) products. Further, users on my website have declared the country of their origin.

Now I need to add to products fields like `allowed_countries` and `blocked_countries`.

- Product can have these fields empty - it will be shown to all users,
- Product can have `allowed_countries` filled - it will be shown onlyto users from that countries,
- Product can have `blocked_countries` filled - it will be shown to all users, except users from `blocked_countries` list.

Such filtering should apply in product catalog, product page and searcher (currently full text search).

How to efficiently design a database for such requirements? What I am caring is performance under quite big load. I was thinking about dynamic columns in MariaDB 10.0.20, but I am not sure about speed of filtering by exactly one country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linking table

products table
(id, other data)

countries table
(id, name, etc)

linking table 
(product_id, country_id, allowed) all not null, 1 means allowed 0 means diallowed

```
select * from product 
left join linking linking_table on linking_table.product_id = product.id 
left join counties_table on (countries_table.id = linking_table.country_id)
```

Now the where changes like this

allowed counties

```
where countries_table.id = (USERS COUNTRY) and linking_table.allowed = 1
```

not allowed

```
where countries_table.id = (USERS COUNTRY) and (linking_table.allowed = 1 or linking_table.allowed is null)
```

The second adds the case where the product doesnt have any black list.

This could return multiple rows per product, so you will need to either group by or return distinct

Comment: How can this return multiple rows per product? You're using `left join` to avoid this.

Comment: Using left join for the case no country link is specified